# Swift container pass data

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, containers

I have problem with container in swift

I need know when user click button in Controller like photos: [image]

how to know when button is clicked in Container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call a method in the `ContainedViewController`, you will first need to get a reference to it.  An easy way to do this is to click on the **Embed segue** in the *Document Outline* view and give this segue an identifier such as `"embedContainedVC"`.

[image: Document Outline View]

---

[image: Name embedded segue]

Then you can use that identifier in `prepareForSegue` to get a reference to the embedded view controller and use that to call a method on that view controller when the button is clicked.

**ViewController.swift:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    var containedVC: ContainedViewController!

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "embedContainedVC" {
            containedVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ContainedViewController
        }
    }

    @IBAction func doClick(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("call contained VC")
        containedVC.clickedClick()
    }
}
```

**ContainedViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class ContainedViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func clickedClick() {
        print("click")
    }
}
```